# How do I query for the max value of a grouped column in Snowflake and then group by another column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to query site analytics data from a Snowflake table and can't find the right query yet.
What I'm looking to do is find the average AMOUNT of FEATURE-A versus FEATURE-B.  But IF there are multiple entries per APPLICATION_ID, I only want the highest amount to factor into the average, as the highest amount represents the final total.  For example, the average AMOUNT for FEATURE-A should be `(40 + 50 + 60)/3`, while the average for FEATURE-B should be `(90 + 100)/2`.
My data looks like this:

| ID | FEATURE | APPLICATION_ID | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 234 | 0 |
| 2 | A | 234 | 40 |
| 3 | A | 235 | 50 |
| 4 | A | 236 | 60 |
| 5 | B | 237 | 70 |
| 6 | B | 237 | 90 |
| 7 | B | 238 | 80 |
| 8 | B | 238 | 100 |

And I want the end result to be:

| FEATURE | AVG_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- |
| A | 50 |
| B | 95 |

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what specific issue are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window functions are applied after `group by`, so you can calculate `max(amount)` per `feature` and `application_id`, then run a windowed `avg()` per `feature` on top of that result.

```
select distinct feature, avg(max(amount)) over (partition by feature) as avg_amt
from t
group by feature, application_id
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to choose the highest value per feature and application and then group:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM tab
   QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY FEATURE, APPLICATION_ID ORDER BY AMOUNT DESC) = 1
)
SELECT feature, AVG(amount) AS AVG_AMOUNT
FROM cte
GROUP BY feature
```

Answer (score 0):

youn can use ROW_number to filter out all unwanted amounts

```
WITH CTE as (SELECT 
FEATURE, AMOUNT
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FEATURE, APPLICATION_ID ORDER BY AMOUNT DESC) rn
FROM mytable)
SELECT FEATURE, AVG(AMOUNT) FROM CTE GROUP BY FEATURE
```

| feature | avg |
| --- | --- |
| B | 85.0 |
| A | 37.5 |